# Table Structure with arrays

Tags: mysql

What is the most efficient way to design the table structure that can address the following problem. My data comes as comma separated text files:

ID,  Name, Married_To, Lived_In, Works_For, DOB 

1325,   Joe,     Ana;Mary;Elen;Ana, Budapest;Paris;Budapest,    IBM, 1965-01-15
2313,   Mark,   Elise,  Bucharest;London;Bucharest;London,  Microsoft, 1972-01-17
3009,   Joe,        Ana;Cindy;Shaquiya, London;NewYork;Bujumbura;NewYork;Bucharest;Bujumbura;NewYork;Bujumbura, Netflix,    1975-01-15

IDs are not unique, but I can create a unique primary key based on a combination of fields.
The two Joe are distinct but there is only one Ana with a fondness for joes (She married first Joe, then the younger Joe, and in old age she remarried her first love Joe)
I need to read the data in a mysql table in such a way that I can efficiently run queries like:

"How many times did Ana married "
"How many people moved from London to Bucharest"
"How many people lived in both London and Bucharest"

The real data is a bit different and contains about 700K records each day, with the array for Lived_in up to 400 elements. MongoDB (or similar)  may be more suitable, but I have to use mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You need one-many relation designs for quicker SQL:

```
persons (id, name, company, dob)
marriages (id, person_id, married_to, date_from)
addresses (id, person_id, city, sequence_id)
```

and here is the SQL for your reports:

```
select count(*) from marriages where married_to='Ana';

select count(*) from addresses a,addresses b
where a.person_id=b.person_id
and a.city='London' and b.city='Bucharest'
and a.sequence_id + 1 = b.sequence_id

select count(*) from addresses a,addresses b
where a.person_id=b.person_id
and a.city='London' and b.city='Bucharest'
```

Comment: There is no "date_from" in the data, the query has to take into account just the sequence i.e london;bucharest moved from London to Bucharest but london;newyork;;;;bucharest did not

Comment: Then assume addresses.id, the bigger the newer, then use this instead: and a.id < b.id

Comment: How many rows would your "addresses" table have? Remember that the Lived_in is sometimes 400 "cities" long. It seems to me that to be able to do what you propose, it will have 400*700K=280 million rows and the last two queries (from address a, address b) would take days to run.Is that the most efficient we can get?